directX mapping for IDA
I'm reversing a DOS application and I see in the code and in the data section some numbers that translate to DirectX Keyboard Scan-codes (standard US keyboard layout) HERE
how can I make IDA to treat a string of those hex numbers as DirectX and not as Ascii?
if its only one numbers like 0x01 I can declare an ENUM and changing that.
but how can I do it if I have in the data section something like this  0x01020304 which should translate to Escape123?

Interesting problem, I don't believe there's one perfect answer. AFAIK IDA won't let you define your own encoding, you can create an array of enum or write a script that patch this encoding into ASCII.
